# How to apply an effect depending on mouse move / position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousemove

I have 3 buttons in position absolute :

```
.micro {
position:absolute;
}

#micro_1 {
left:1165px;
top:176px;
}

#micro_2 {
left:800px;
top:300px;
}

#micro_3 {
left:300px;
top:400px;
}
```

I would like to fade these 3 elements when the mouse move and come closer to one of the images.
If mouse comes closer to image 1, images 1 is fading in. Images 2 and images 3 are fading out.
And so on.

I can use jQuery to know the mouse position :

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    $('#mouse_position').html("mouse position: x=" + e.pageX + "; y=" + e.pageY);
```

So i guess i can do some math to apply the effect.

What i've done :

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
        $('#mouse_position').html("mouse position: x=" + e.pageX + "; y=" + e.pageY);
        if (e.pageX > 394 && e.pageX < 533) {
            $('#lueur_video_1').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#lueur_video_2').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#lueur_video_3').fadeOut('slow');
        }

        if (e.pageX > 533 && e.pageX < 722) {
            $('#lueur_video_2').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#lueur_video_1').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#lueur_video_3').fadeOut('slow');
        }

        if (e.pageX > 722 && e.pageX < 1116) {
            $('#lueur_video_3').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#lueur_video_1').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#lueur_video_2').fadeOut('slow');
        }
```

Comment: Can you create a working version of what you have so far on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Explosion Pills see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/2khgw/1/ It's really basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the mouse position (e.pageX / e.pageY) to the center of the image and set the opacity based on that.  You can check where the elements are on the page with `$("#micro_3").offset()`.

You will need to decide on the minimum and maximum distance for the fading on your own.  When it's out of the maximum distance, opacity is 0 and inside the minimum, opacity is 1.  For anything in between calculate the opacity by `(Range - CurrentDistance) / Range`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm trying your solution which is obviously more precise. I've edited my question to show what i've tried (very basic but the effect is nice).

Comment: @SébastienGicquel you're close, but you can't just use `pageX` if you also want to use `pageY`.  A great man named Pythagoras created a theorem that calculates the distance between two points based on the right angle they form.  Additionally, use `.css('opacity')`.  `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` animate, so they will end up animating continuously since `mousemove` is triggered with such a high frequency.  If you want animation, try using CSS transitions on opacity.